# NameError: name 'custom_data_home' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=custom_data_home)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=custom_data_home)
NameError: name 'custom_data_home' is not defined
```

i am getting `NameError`, i searched in net for solutions, i didn't get any relevant answers.
i even tries installing  "custom_data_home" using easy_install . it says it could not find.
pls help me on this.

Comment: do you have `custom_data_home` parameter? try to print it before the `mnist = ....` line.

Comment: pls explain ..... i could not understand what u r telling

Comment: sorry i could not understand what "custom_data_home parameter" is.......  pls explain...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about sklearn, but it looks like you are trying to use the example from this page: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/mldata.html

In that example `custom_data_home` is a variable containing the path to where you want the data stored. If you leave it off it says it should default to just `data`.

Basically in your script you have not defined `custom_data_home`. That is what `NameError` is telling you.

If you are going to use a variable, like `custom_data_home` you have to define it in some way. Your script doesn't know what `custom_data_home` is.

```
custom_data_home = '/path/to/my/data'
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=custom_data_home)
```

That should work.

Comment: just leave it off:
`mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')` and your data should be stored in the `data` directory.
Or define the `custom_data_home` parameter before using it.
`custom_data_home = '/path/to/where/I/want/my/data/'; mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=custom_data_home)`

Comment: thank you so much .....it worked                     custom_data_home = '/path/to/my/data'
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=custom_data_home)